# Passive voice with ditransitive verb, which is the patient?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, subjects, objects, ditransitivity

If I were to make the following constructions, how would I label the parts of the sentence using passive voice terminology? Alice seems to be the agent in both these constructions, but which is the patient, and is there a term for the third argument?

1. "The book was given to Bob by Alice."
2. "Bob was given the book by Alice."

I would like to know both the terminology that is used traditionally in English grammar as well as a general term that can be applied to other languages, since I want to compare it to other languages that may have different syntax or structures.

Comment: Both are passive sentences; i.e, the rule of Passive has applied from an original sentence _Alice gave the book to Bob_. The difference is that the rule of Dative (_She gave the book to Bob==> She gave Bob the book_) has promoted the receiver _Bob_ to direct object status before Passive in (2), but not in (1), which still has _the book_ as the direct object before Passive. Oh, and the only patient is _the book_; semantically, in all of these sentences, _Alice_ is the Source, Bob the Goal, and the book the Trajector, which is normal in ditransitive sentences.

Comment: I'd say that the patients are "the book" and "Bob", which are functioning as subjects of 1. and 2. respectively. In both cases "Alice" is the actor.

Comment: Note that, for me, _patient_ is a semantic term, and has no meaning in syntax.